# oracle find people whose 65th birthday is 30 days in the future

Tags: sql, oracle

From oracle database I am trying to capture people who will turn 65 years old in 30 days in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post data structure, sample data, required result and what you tried so far. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you find something useful to create a good example

Comment: Do a SELECT, add a WHERE clause where you check current_date between 65 years - 30 days and 65 years.

Comment: SELECT months_between(sysdate+30 ,date-

Comment: select MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate+30,date_of_birth)

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from   your_table
where  birthdate between add_months(sysdate, -12*65) and add_months(sysdate, -12*65) + 30
```

Logically, you want to add 65 years to birthdate and then check if it's between today and 30 days from today. Oracle only has an add_months function, no add_years, so you need to multiply by 12. Finally, I moved the add_months to the right side; if the optimizer is smart, it will do the calculation only once, not once per row - and not applying a function to "birthdate" allows use of an index, if you have one defined on that column.